# Unable to layout composite field items

Tags: extjs

I am using Ext JS 3.4 and in the composite field, there are three fields, code is as below:

```
            xtype: 'compositefield',
            name: 'comboField',
            fieldLabel: 'Partner with',
            width: 400,
            cItems:[{
              xtype: 'combo',
              name: 'partnerTypeCombo',
              value: 'ProviderName',
              mode: 'local',
              store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                  fields: ['id', 'displayValue'],
                  data: [
                    ['ProviderName', 'Provider Partner Name'],
                    ['OtherProvider', 'Other Provider Partner']
                  ]
              }),
              valueField: 'id',
              displayField: 'displayValue',
              listeners: {
                scope: this,
                select: function(combo, record, index) {
                  var providerField = this.formPanel.getForm().findField('comboField_providerPartnerNameField');
                  var otherProviderField = this.formPanel.getForm().findField('comboField_otherProviderPartnerNameField');
                  if (combo.value == "OtherProvider") {
                    providerField.setVisible(false);
                    otherProviderField.setVisible(true);
                  }
                  else {
                    providerField.setVisible(true);
                    otherProviderField.setVisible(false);
                  }
                }
              }
            }, {
                xtype: 'spacer',
                width: 10,
                flex: 0
              }, {
                xtype: 'modellinkfield',
                name: 'providerPartnerNameField',
                modelLevelType: 'Organization',
                modelType: 'Organization',
                pickerReport: {
                    reportName: 'TMS.SupplierVendorOrgPicker',
                    targetLevelType: 'Organization'
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'otherProviderPartnerNameField',
                hidden: true
            }]
```

By using the above code and **without hiding any field**, I got the below result

[image]

But My expectation is

- By default third field (which is text field) should be hidden
- On selecting Combobox values, the next two fields should be visible/hidden.
  Like if dropdown field value is "Provider Partner Name" then only second 
  field (modeling field) should be visible (shown as below)

[image]

- And if dropdown field value is "Other Provider Name" then only third
  field (i.e text field) should be visible.
  But I am unable to achieve this third objective. I am getting the following output for this (the field is getting overridden)

[image]

And I am expecting the following output.

[image]

Looks like this may be some layout issue or maybe I need to apply some CSS style to handle this. Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve this issue by using below code :

```
otherProviderField.ownerCt.doLayout();
```